# Interesting probability question - husband and wife committee variation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

Twenty husbands and wives (ten couples) are randomly divided into two groups. What is the probability that at exactly 4 wives are in the same group
as their husbands?

Attempt: There are $\binom{40}{2}=780$ numbers of posible committees by dividing the couples into two groups. The way I thought about this problem was to have a bag filled with two colored balls both numbered 1-10 and drawing them out one by one. If there are exactly 4 couples together in a group that means there must be 1 male female pair in a committee with a different partner, or with the ball example two different colored balls with different numbers. So the number of ways of having a committee with exactly 4 couples is the number of pairs $$(1,2), \dots (1,10), (2,3), \dots (2,10), (3,4), \dots (3,10), \dots (9,10) = \sum_{i=1}^9 i = 45$$
therefore the probability is $45/780.$ Can anyone confirm this answer? I think it is wrong and I also think there is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: "random" means that each person has a $\frac 12$ probability of being sent to one or the other group?  If so, the probability that a given wife ends up in the same group as her husband is $\frac 12$, so we just have a standard binomial distribution.

Comment: Just to say....your value seems, on its face, to be far too low.  Assuming I am interpreting "randomly divided" correctly (possibly a bad assumption) then the expectation would be $5$ wives grouped with their spouse.  $4$ would then seem very likely...

Comment: Do you mean to say that the group of $20$ is split up in two groups of $10$?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  I am assuming the size of the two groups is not preset (as you don't say anything about the size), and that people are assigned to one group or the other independently of each other.  You might also be assuming that there are two groups each of size $10$ (so each person still has probability $\frac 12$ of winding up in either group BUT the result for one person changes the probability for another).  Or you might mean something entirely different.

Comment: 'dividing the couples into two groups' - if you mean $equal$ groups and 40 people, it is $\binom{40}{20}$. If you mean 20 couples and equal groups, it is $\binom{20}{10}$

Comment: ${40\choose2}=780$ only counts the number of ways you can divide the $40$ people into one group of $2$ and one group of $38$.  There are many more ways than that to divide the people into two groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me what exactly is meant by "...are randomly divided into $2$ groups...". I preassume that the group of $20$ is randomly split up in a group $A$ and a group $B$ both containing $10$ persons.

If there are exactly $k$ married couples in group $A$ then *automatically*
there are exactly $k$ married couples in group $B$.

So exactly $4$ women in the same group as their husband requires
that $k=2$.

There are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ married couples.
There are $\binom{4}{2}$ different ways to
put $2$ of those couples in group $A$ and the other $2$ in group $B$.

There are $2^{6}$ ways to choose $6$ persons from the remaining
$12$ such that among them there are no couples. The chosen $6$ are put in group $A$ and the remaining $6$ in group
$B$.

There are in total $\binom{20}{10}$ ways to choose $10$ persons
for group $A$.

Probability:$$\frac{\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{2}2^{6}}{\binom{20}{10}}\sim0.4365$$

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking is wrong. You're assuming that having exactly 4 couples in one group would mean there's space for 2 other people left in that group. But in that case, the partners to these two people would be in the other group, as well as everybody else - and "everybody else" is four more couples, so you would have a total of 8 couples, not 4.

The only way to have exactly 4 couples would be to have exactly 6 non-couples, so 6 people are in one group and their partners in the other. This makes it clear that you would have to have 2 couples in one group, 2 couples in the other to total 4 couples.

I'm really bad at probabilities and I also haven't done it for years, so I'll leave the math to somebody who's better at it (sorry).

Comment: That's assuming that the groups must be equal

Comment: @Snufsan If that assumption is not made then no answer is possible. E.g. if one of the group has size $1$ then it is for certain that more than $4$ women are in the same group as their husband. That can be different with other group sizes.

Comment: "If there are exactly 4 couples together in a group that means there must be 1 male female pair in a committee with a different partner" --> this is heavily suggesting that each group holds 10 people (or that this is at least how OP understands the question). But of course you're right, it wasn't specified.

Comment: @drhab I mean that the groups doesnt have to be in the same size in every partitioning.

Comment: @B.Altmann that's something you infered from the solution of the OP, which could be wrong or assuming wrong assumptions.

Comment: @Snufsan I only commented OPs solution, though, not the original problem, so it only makes sense to assume the same things they did. I pointed out that their reasoning was - based on their assumptions - wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm considering the following model: Each person is assigned to one of the groups $H$ or $T$ by throwing a coin.

For any given couple the probability that both members are assigned to the same group is  ${\displaystyle{1\over2}}$.

The probability $P$ that exactly four couples stay together then computes to
$$P={{10\choose 4}\over 2^{10}}={105\over512}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that there are $10$ people in each group

The number of "singles" in a group must necessarily be matched by an equal number in the other group, and thus so, too, must  the number of couples, which means that for  exactly $4$ couples,
each group must have $2$ couples.

Two couples can be chosen and lined up in $\binom{10}2\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7 = 226,800$ ways and for the remaining, the rest of the numerator ensures that no other couple is selected

$$\begin{align}Pr = & \frac{226,800\cdot 16\cdot 14\cdot 12\cdot 10\cdot 8\cdot 6}{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11} \approx 0.4365\end{align}$$

Comment: "the groups are unlabelled". Then the denumerator must be $\frac12\binom{20}{10}$. Btw, that gives drhabs answer.

Comment: @Vera: You are right. I have reworked the answer in a somewhat different way.

Comment: That's a nice answer +1

Comment: @Vera: Thanks, glad that you like it !

Comment: Why can't you do 20*1*18*1*16*14*12*10*8*6/(20*19*...*11), since the first person can be selected in 20 ways, their spouse can be selected in 1 way, the next person can be selected in 18 ways, their spouse can be selected in 1 way, etc?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying. It gives an answer , by the way, of  $\approx 0.0007$ !

Answer (score 1):

You Could easily count the number of such partitions for a general partitions, and then dependent of your probability space you could use that to infer the probability.

We want $4$ couples that are in the same group and $6$ that are in different. So we assume that there is two different groups $A, B$ and we later divide by $2$ so that cases $(A,B) , (A',B')$ such that $A'= B$ will be the same in our point of view.

So if there are two different groups we, first we decide which couples going to be in the same group - ${10}\choose{4}$ possible selections.

For each of those couples, we decide whether it will be in $A$ or $B$ - $2^4$ possibilities.

Now finally, we decide about the other couples. since they cant be in the same group, if we decide that the husband is in $A$ it would mean that the wife must be in $B$, so we should just choose for the husbands their group - $2^6$ possibilities.

Multiplying them all we get that we have ${{10}\choose{4}} \cdot 2^{10}$ such partitions into different groups.